# Android video recorder application - 'Video cannot play' error

Tags: android, video, encoding, media, recorder

I have developed an android application to record video. The application is **working smoothly in my mobile**, recorded video can be played in other devices along with phone. However, I have to install this application on a Android-X86 image. *The device is a Lenevo Ideapad 330*. Application run very smoothly and can record the video. However, while I try to play the recorded video in the same (and others) device, it shows - the video can't play. The file size is large enough.

Following are the Media Recorder source code-

```
mMediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.SURFACE);
    mMediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
    if (mNextVideoAbsolutePath == null || mNextVideoAbsolutePath.isEmpty()) {
        mNextVideoAbsolutePath = getVideoFilePath(getActivity());
    }
    mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(mNextVideoAbsolutePath);
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(10000000);
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(30);
    //mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(1000000);
    //mMediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(18);
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoSize(mVideoSize.getWidth(), mVideoSize.getHeight());
    //mMediaRecorder.setVideoSize(1280, 720);
    //mMediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(30);
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);
    mMediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
    int rotation = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
    switch (mSensorOrientation) {
        case SENSOR_ORIENTATION_DEFAULT_DEGREES:
            mMediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(DEFAULT_ORIENTATIONS.get(rotation));
            break;
        case SENSOR_ORIENTATION_INVERSE_DEGREES:
            mMediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(INVERSE_ORIENTATIONS.get(rotation));
            break;
    }

    mMediaRecorder.prepare();
```

There might not issues with others method as the video recording is working smoothly in phone.

I am wondering whether the problem might be related to the output format or VideoEncoder. I tried several encoder including 3GPP, VP8, H263. No luck yet.

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks.